# Stretchy header effect

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-sliver

I'm looking to create a header effect like this:

[image: stretchy header]

Specifically, I want it so when the user overscrolls on iOS, the image should zoom to fill the extra space. Then, on Android and iOS, when the user starts scrolling down the screen, the header should be scrolled away with a parallax effect.

I pulled the above screen video from this package here: https://github.com/gskbyte/GSKStretchyHeaderView

Another example can be found here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/tutorial-creating-stretchy-layouts-on-ios-using-auto-layout-3fa974fa5e28

I was playing around with `SliverPersistentHeader`s and `FlexibleSpaceBar`s but I was unable to get this effect quite how I wanted it.

Answer (score 3):

Think what you are going to need is Sliver app bar with the flexible space bar.  Take a look here: https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! `SliverAppBar` is handy. However, I still can't figure out how I can get the stretchy background effect that I'm looking for.

Comment: @maxlapides hi, were you able to achieve this? I'm also trying to get this effect.

Comment: @HiroshiHorie I haven't been successful yet! I did open an issue on GitHub, though, so if this is also an issue for you please https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27373

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [approach](https://github.com/diegoveloper/flutter_stretchy_header/blob/master/lib/stretchy_header.dart) from [stretchy header](https://pub.dev/packages/stretchy_header) package

[image]